# Как узнать наименование всех столбцов, значение которых Null

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Есть база данных с множеством таблиц. 
Есть какой-либо способ узнать наименование таблиц и столбцов в них, в которых во всех записях по столбцу стоит значение null?

Искал в на форумах и msdn, там только последнее изменение таблицы и типы полей в них.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

скрин для примера

Comment: nullable имеете ввиду?

Comment: @tcpack4 Нет, Nullable предполагает, что значение null в столбце присутствует, но могут быть и данные.
Мне же надо найти все столбцы которые не  использовались и их значение null

Comment: Попробуйте sp_msforeachtable

Answer (score 2):

Тупо

```
SELECT MIN(field1), MIN(field2), ... MIN(fieldN)
FROM `table`;
```

Если в поле ВСЕ записи содержат NULL - то и в выборке в соотв. поле будет NULL. Иначе там будет некое значение. Если не нравится MIN - можно MAX, результат тот же.

Comment: Не подходит.
Данный select вернёт данные по одной таблице, их в базе порядка 500-600 и в ручную перебирать долго. Да и количество полей в каждой таблице варьируется от 1 до 20 и более.

Comment: Ну так влезьте в INFORMATION_SCHEMA и получите оттуда список таблиц, и для каждой список NULLable полей, и динамически стройте запросы. Ну типа `SELECT table_name, column_name FROM database.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE is_nullable='YES';`

Comment: MIN не работает на типах _bit, xml, geography, geometry, image, text, ntext_. Идею динамических запросов поддерживаю. Наверное лучше COUNT. Хм.. COUNT нельзя на _image, text, ntext_ (obsolete типы).

Comment: @i-one Ну при наличии таких типов для этих полей придётся, получается, считать `SUM(CASE WHEN fieldN IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` и сравнивать с нулём? ой, тормоза-а-а...